# how to print the top k-row indexes from the weakest to the strongest

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make a numpy array by using `np.random.randint(2, size=(4,4))`.
And its size can be changeable.

I want to print the top k-row indexes from the weakest to the strongest (weaker: smaller number of ones) so I made a code like this

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 2, size = (r,c))
r, c = 5, 5
print(a)

def weak(array, k):
    np.array(array)
    sum_nums = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        sum_nums.append((i, sum([i])))
            sorted_sum_nums = sorted(sum_nums, key=lambda x: x[1])

            answer = [idx[0] for idx in sorted_sum_nums[:int(k)]]
            return answer

weak(a, 5)
```

I try this code, but it doesn't work well.
How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the indentation, you return prematurely :

```
def weak(array, k):
    np.array(array)
    sum_nums = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        sum_nums.append((i, sum([i])))
        sorted_sum_nums = sorted(sum_nums, key=lambda x: x[1])

        answer = [idx[0] for idx in sorted_sum_nums[:int(k)]]
    return answer # <== here
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should initialized r and c before you call them, then you called  weak(a,5)
a is not initialized i think you wanted to call arr instead. Below I returned minimum row of array

```
import numpy as np

r, c = 5, 5
arr = np.random.randint(0, 2, size = (r,c))

def weak(array, k):
    array =np.array(array)
    sum_nums = []
    summed =[[],[]]
    for each in array:
        summ = sum(each)
        summed[0].append(summ)
        summed[1].append(array.index(each))
    
    return summed[1][summed[0].index(min(summed[0]))]

weak(arr, 5)
```

If you want to print result to screen.

```
print(weak(arr,5))
```